# Prevent backward lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some values given by clock time, where the first column is the time. However, the values until 2 o clock still belong to the current day. Given

```
3 1
12 4
18 1
21 2
1 3
2 0
```

named as `test.data`, I'd like to print this in gnuplot:

```
set xrange [0:24]
plot 'test.data' with lines
```

However, the plot contains a backward line. It's striking through the whole diagram.

Is there a way to tell gnuplot to explicitly not print such backward lines, or even better, print them wrapping around the x axis (e.g. in my example drawing the line as a forward line up to 24, and then continuing it at 0)?

Note: The x axis of the plot should still start at 0 and end at 24.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but I am not fully certain that is what you wanted.  Can you elaborate some more?  Do these represent the same clock day, or are you measuring days as from 3am until 3am of the next day?  If it is from the same clock day, why are some times occurring so much later in the file?  Does my answer address what you are after, or are you looking for something different?

Comment: @Matthew Many thanks. However, what I require is that the x axis start at 0 and goes to 24 (not from 3 to 3). I added this now in a note. The measurements from 2am occur technically already in the next day, but should still be printed as if they occured in the current day.

Comment: So, do you want the line with 3 to have an x-axis label of 0?  Also, do you want those last to lines to occur on the left or right of the graph?  What should the labels on those read?

Comment: I updated my answer to show one case with the x-axis ranging from 0 to 24 (currently the second graph).  I still need answers to my additional questions to know if this addresses your problem.  It might be helpful if you can even provide an image of what you want - it doesn't have to look good, be exact, or include all of your data, and you can even sketch it in a paint program.  Something to show what you are looking for may make your question clearer.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks again, but graph 2 is also not what I need. What I need is the image that my question proposes, but without the backward line from 21 to 1, and, if possible, an additional line connecting 21 and 1 by a forward line that ends at 24 and continues at 0. These are all modifications, no re-scaling etc.

Comment: I'm still not fully clear.  Do you want a line which goes off the right side of the graph and comes back in on the left (a Pac-Man effect)?  If so that isn't likely to be possible.  Gnuplot can't wrap graphs, and even doing it manually, you would have to compute the slope and somehow add an extra point.  If you can do some outside preprocessing, adding a blank line before the `1 3` line will insert a discontinuity into the plot and prevent gnuplot from connecting those points.  Of course, you could always sort the data too.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks, that's already the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as wrapping over the edge of the graph (a pac-man like effect), gnuplot can't do that on it's own.  Even doing it manually, you would have to somehow calculate the right point to re-enter the graph based on the slope of the connecting line, and insert a new point into the data to control where the re-entry line enters, and where the exiting line exits.  This would require external processing.

If you can do some outside preprocessing, adding a blank line before the 1 3 line will insert a discontinuity into the plot and prevent gnuplot from connecting those points (see `help datafile` for how gnuplot handles blank lines). Of course, you could always sort the data too.

I would recommend sorting the data before plotting, but if you do want to do this wrapping effect, the following python program (**wrapper.py**) will set up the data for it

```
data = [tuple(map(float,x.strip().split(" "))) for x in open("data.txt","r")]
data2 = sorted(data)

back_in_to = data2[0]
out_from = data2[-1]

xdelta = back_in_to[0] + 24 - out_from[0]
ydelta = back_in_to[1] - out_from[1]

slope = ydelta/xdelta

outy = out_from[1] + (24-out_from[0])*slope

print(0,outy)
for x in data2:
    print(*x)
    if x[0]==data[-1][0]: print("")
print(24,outy)
```

It reads in the data (assumed to be in **data.txt**, and calculates the points where a line should leave the graph and where it should re-enter, adding these points to the sorted data.  It adds a blank line after the last point in the original graph, causing the break in the line.  We can then plot like

```
plot "< wrapper.py" with lines
```

[image]

If we look at your original plot

[image]

we see the backward line that you referred to which reaches from the furthest right point to the next left point.  The plot that the python program pre-processed reaches through the right of the graph to move back to this point.

Comment: Many thanks. It's probably the best possible solution.